# How should I unit test my Pyramid app's route matching?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyramid

I am writing a Pyramid web application that uses URL dispatch for mapping routes to views.

I would like to write a set of unit tests that provide Pyramid's "route matcher" with a variety of paths, and then assert that:

1. the correct view is called
2. the `request.matchdict` contains the expected contents

How can I do this at a proper *unit* test level (as opposed to at a functional level, by submitting actual HTTP requests)? Which "unit" in Pyramid actually does the route matching, and how can I access it to test my app's configured routing?

**NOTE**: I know I can do this using *functional* testing, but I am asking this question because I want to know how to test it much more narrowly--just the route matching portion. I suppose what I'm looking for might be considered an integration test and not a unit test, because it touches multiple components...

I have Googled and read relevant Pyramid documentation, including [Dispatching URLs To Views With Routing](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/routing.html) and [Unit, Integration, and Functional Testing](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/testing.html). Nothing I have seen shows me how to test my application's configured routes without doing functional tests.

Comment: Have you looked at [Unit, Integration, and Functional Testing](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/testing.html) on the Pyramid site?

Comment: Yes, and I can perform the assertions I'm interested in by using the functional testing that page describes. The thing I'm wondering about is how to accomplish a proper, narrow _unit_ test of specifically the route mapping functionality.

Comment: I'm interested in this because I'm curious to learn more about how Pyramid works, and also because functional testing is generally slower, more brittle and harder to maintain than (judicious) unit testing.

Comment: [Dispatching URLs To Views With Routing](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/routing.html) has a unittest example.

Comment: Yes, that's true. That page has one unit test and one functional test. The unit test it shows, though, does not demonstrate how to _unit_ test the route mapping functionality. Again, I _could_ write functional tests for this, but that is not what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a public api to do this in Pyramid. However, there is a private and pretty stable API for it.. you've been warned.

Route matching doesn't occur on just patterns but also predicates so it requires a full request object to do matching, not just a url.

```
registry = config.registry or request.registry
mapper = registry.getUtility(pyramid.interfaces.IRoutesMapper)
result = mapper(request)
route, matchdict = result['route'], result['match']
if route is not None:
    route  # pyramid.interfaces.IRoute object
    matchdict  # request.matchdict
```

The raw `IRoute` objects themselves **are** available on a public api via the introspector. You can look these up and match against them on a per-route basis, but this will ignore the route ordering inherent to Pyramid.

```
introspector = config.registry or request.registry.introspector
intr = introspector.get('routes', route_name)
route = intr['route']
match = route.match(path)
if match is not None:
    route  # pyramid.interfaces.IRoute object
    match  # request.matchdict
```

The route also has the predicates on it which you can pass the `request` to in order to determine if the predicates pass.